# SEPAL creating Optical Mosaic get following error message "ServerException: The specified location constraint is not valid."

Tags: image-mosaic, sepal

When creating an Optical Mosaic on SEPAL I get the following error message

> ServerException: The specified location constraint is not valid.

After selecting an area of interest, the date and the satellite imagery I have tried downloading/retrieving the mosaic and I am constantly getting the same error. It has been two weeks that I get this error message, and I have tried selecting different locations, different dates and different sources (landsat 4-5, landsat 7, landsat 8). In the past I did the same steps, and didn't have any problems. I still have resources, but each time I try retrieving a mosaic the instance spending is going up. Not sure what the problem is and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug that has been resolved. It happened for users not using their own Google account, but relied on the service account and retrieved imagery to their workspace. There was an error in our Google Cloud Storage configuration.